Can I use my Raspberry Pi 5 as a Nintendo Switch USB controller?
Basically I have a Raspberry Pi 5 connected with my Nintendo Switch via a USB-A male to male cable, and I want to use it as a USB controller, so that I can script macros to my Switch.
I'm very new to Raspberry Pi and to be honest I've never used USB for communication, so I don't even know if it's possible or even a good idea.
Currently I'm not even able to detect the Switch via usb and I have no Idea what I'm doing wrong. Whenever I use the lsusb command it doesn't recognize the system. I've read that I should change the Raspberry config file so that the port would work as a peripheral and not as a host, so I added this at the end:
# Configure one USB-A port as a gadget (device mode)
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral

# Keep the other USB-A port in host mode
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

I wanted to make only one port work as a gadget, while the others worked as host, but even with the change I still wasn't even able to detect the console with the lsusb command.

I don't pretend to know anything about Nintendo but the only port you can use in peripheral mode is the USB-C power port (which is not without problems). Pretty much by definition a hub cannot.

Thanks! After a full night of research, I've gathered that using another microcontroller as a USB gadget would be smarter!
